# How do I find the duplicate lines in a file, output them with the filename, and do this for an entire directory?

Tags: shell-script, sort, uniq

I have few files under directory and need to find duplicate lines in each file and display the file name to identify which file has duplicate.

I tried: `for i in *.*;do sort $i | uniq -d ; done`

It display duplicate lines but how to display file name as well to identify which file has duplicate?

And above command work only for csv,.txt files is there any way to check .xlsx file as well?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `sed` to add a prefix to each line - you already have the filename in `$i`.

This should do it:

```bsh
for i in *.*; do sort $i|uniq -d |sed -e "s/^/$i:/"; done
```

expanded for easy reading:

```bsh
for i in *.*; do
  sort $i | uniq -d | sed -e "s/^/$i:/";
done
```

2. xlsx files are really just zip directories of files, you can unzip the xlsx and view the contents under `file/xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml`. The files are in xml though so you'll need to parse them before trying to process them.

Comment: what's the meaning of `"s/^/$i:/"`?

Comment: It's a regular expression that basically says go to the beginning of the line `^` and add `$i:` where `$i` is the name of the file set in the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Option for finding files with duplicate lines.
Please note that blank lines can also match the pattern.

```
awk 'D[$0]++ {print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.*
```

To exclude empty lines, you need to add another filter, for example:

```
awk '/./ && D[$0]++ {print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.*
```

And so you can exclude lines with whitespace characters

```
gawk '/\S/ && D[$0]++ {print FILENAME; nextfile}' *.*
```

And this is the answer to your task (without blank and empty lines):

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {delete D;j=0} /[^[:blank:]]/ && (D[$0]++ == 1) {if(! j++ ) print "name: " FILENAME; print}' *.*
```